# Error in a Histogram with GGPLOT2 (R)

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I am triying to obtain a histogram. This is my code:

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x=skus, fill=as.factor(stars))) +
+     geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="identity") +
+     geom_vline(data=cdf, aes(xintercept=rating.mean,  colour=as.factor(stars)),
+                linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

When I execute this code I obtain the next graphic:

[image]

This is not a histogram. What is my code mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just I have detected my mistake. I am defined the binwidth as .5. I only have to increment this rate to obtain a good histogram like binwidth=50